# GCM 3.0 Topics bug: successful subscription, but sometimes no notifications

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

Sending a GCM notification to a hardcoded `InstanceID` seems to always work for all of my android/ios devices, but sending it to a topic has issues.

Even after a successful subscription to a `topic`, a device could not receive notifications from that topic, while other devices work.
Looks like there is a chance that an InstanceID for a device will just not work when subscribed to a topic. Resubscribing does nothing. Deleting this token and getting a new one seems to fix that issue.

Note: once a device associated with an InstanceID starts receiving notifications from a topic, it seems to consistently work. If it does not receive a notification that it should, it does start working later.

Note 2: by "works", I mean that the InstanceID device receives the notification as expected.

What's going on? How am I ever supposed to handle this issue? Is topic messaging unusable?

Comment: It wouldn't be available if its unusable, I think. Can you mention which device you are facing the issue with? and perhaps, some implementation especially `GCMListenerService` or `GCMBroadcastReceiver` whichever you use?

Comment: @KayAnn my code is implemented perfectly. The problem was on GCM's end. It doesn't seem to be happening anymore though. 

I would have all my devices be report successful registration to the same topic (I tried this on about 6 different ones). Same code on all 6 devices. So I pinged the GCM server. 3 devices would receive notifications, while the other 3 didn't. I unsubscribed, resubscribed - all successfully. Still couldn't get notifications on the bad 3. See my answer

Comment: yeah I see it was an issue with the InstanceID. Glad you got it working now. Probably the prior InstanceID didn't get subscribed properly for some reason for the 3 devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the InstanceID token and requesting a new one fixed the issue for me.

Must have had a bum InstanceID token.